# How do I force my web.config to rebuild every time my project is launched

Tags: .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, caching, web-config

I've been working on tightening up my application deployment, validating that a list of environment variables exist and have values before launching the application.

I've got a standard web.config file that reads in environment variables from a file launchSettings.json.

In my startup.cs class I have a configuration validator class that checks that the list defined in my launchSettings file that validates if the key exists, the value isn't empty and the value doesn't contain '#{ENV' (which is the value of a web.config item that's key has not been added to the launchSettings file)

The problem is.
When I run my application for the first time with all the keys and values filled out. It works fine.

When I go into LaunchSettings and comment out a line and then rebuild the application, my web.config does not update to show the update to the particular key/value in question.

Is there any way to make sure that the web.config reads and updated version of my launchSettings file each time the project is rebuilt so that it updates the values as described?

Or is there another method that I haven't stumbled upon that helps me validate environment variables before launching an application?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: .NET Core doesn't use we.config?

Comment: @DavidG I have a web.config in this particular project. Just double checked and it's .NET Core 2.1

Comment: `web.config` is used for IIS, I don't really get why you are trying to configure your app from there, rather than doing it all in `appSettings.json`?

Comment: @DavidG so you're saying I should follow something similar to this [link](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/net-development/asp-net-core-3-0-configuration-factsheet/)? Where by web.config should be converted to a .json file and loaded - where environment variables are set and published from within a the startup.cs class with ConfigurationBuilder?

Comment: I would recommend that yes, web.config is only a bootstrap to get .NET Core apps running in IIS. Let's say you switch to another web server, or run in Linux, then that won't work any more.

Comment: @DavidG yeah that's cool. I use IIS for the app in question so it was an assumption to stick with web.config as it maps appropriately to IIS environment variables.

Comment: @DavidG's point is that ASP.NET Core doesn't use web.config. It's there only for loading the ASP.NET Core hosting module for the purposes of IIS. You should not use web.config for anything else, regardless of whether you're hosting in IIS or not. Configure your app the ASP.NET Core way.

Comment: Also, launchSettings.json is *only* for development, when hosting with IIS Express within Visual Studio or running with `dotnet run [project]`. It is not used otherwise, and shouldn't be relied on.